# Angular CLI - error Invalid blueprint: guard

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I'am using Angular CLI to generate components, services etc. everything works fine. Just when tying to create a guard it throws the following error:

```
Invalid blueprint: guard
```

After a couple of searches, I was not really able to find a helpful solution. The command I'am running following the documentation on GitHub [generate guard](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-guard) is:

```
ng generate guard [name]
```

Any idea please what could be the reason?

Comment: what version of CLI you are using?

Comment: angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 8.0.0

Comment: update it to latest version and try again

Comment: @ Aravind: works fine! But why down voting me!!?

Comment: I didn't do that shall I add the same as answer?

Comment: Yes, Please... go for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149370/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-aravind).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `1.0.0-beta.28.3` CLI version, it will not support the guard generation.

Update the Angular CLI

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

[**Refer Docs**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli) for more guidance.

Comment: Updating Angular CLI was the solution.... but this is the command which did run successfully for me:

`npm rm -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clear
npm i -g @angular/cli`